# How to route 2 interfaces to the same destination IP address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, ftp, raspberry-pi

I have a RPi with two different interfaces (wwan0, wwan1) each one with one IP provided by two different wireless network operators.

The RPi has to communicate with a server for the correct fucntioning of the system. The problem is that the two interfaces have to connect with the server, that is, with the same IP address. Therefore it is difficult to get the goal as the RPi will have the output route to get the server just to one interface (wwan0 or wwan1).

As the type of traffic that I want to send is different, could it exist any special routing to do it? I want to send ftp* traffic through wwan0 and the rest of the traffic trhough wwan1. Is it possible?

*The FTP traffic is started by the server (RPi <-----FTP req--- Server).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the rasberry-pi running as an operating system?

Comment: Raspberry pi 3 b+ and Raspbian stretch